# C++ virtual inheritance with abstract class for basic implementation of some math functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-inheritance

I have troubles with homework. The task is to implement files included in main.cpp so the program will work. main.cpp is the file we get from our teacher - we can't make any changes in it. At the end of it there is written a desired output. (note: there shouldn't be any overloaded operators).

This is what I did so far: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ffzkdaVoYK8Qovic

I can't get it to work properly. I don't know what I am doing wrong:

1. There must be some error with Differential. Teacher said that we don't need to use clone() method in it - so I didn't - but when I do, in constructor instead of setF, I'm getting segmentation fault. The same happens in function in(), when I'm trying to return the result according to the formula - and I don't get why it happens.
2. I get -5 instead of 5 (see output below main.cpp). Some math error? I can't spot it.
3. I have a feeling my class hierarchy is really bad. What should it be instead? (Guessing from the lecture there should be virtual inheritance, multiple inheritance and a solution to diamond problem - but well, that's just my guess.) I'm also getting some warnings when compiling and I didn't fix them because I think I just did the hierarchy wrong and if I fix it the problem will be gone.
4. In general, what can I fix in my code to make it better?

Here is main.cpp (it's also in the link to my solution):

```
#include "Fun.h"
#include "Elementary.h"
#include "Compound.h"
#include "Differential.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "=====-===== 2 =====-=====" << std::endl;

    Fun * lfun = Linear::create()->a(2.)->b(-1.);                        // This is ax + b = 2x-1
    Fun * sfun = new Sinus;

    std::cout << lfun->value(0.1)   << " "  << lfun->value(0)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << sfun->value(0.1)   << " "  << sfun->value(0)  << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=====-===== 2 =====-=====" << std::endl;

    Fun * qbase = Quadratic::create()->a(1)->b(0.)->c(-4.);
    Fun * qfun = qbase->clone();                                         // Cloning
    std::cout << qbase->value(0.1)  << " "  << qbase->value(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << qfun->value(0.1)   << " "  << qfun->value(0)  << std::endl;

    delete qbase;
    std::cout << qfun->value(0.1)   << " "  << qfun->value(0)  << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=====-===== 2 =====-=====" << std::endl;
    Differential diff(0.01);                                     // 0.01 is h

    std::cout <<  "value of differential from lfun in 1.0  = " << diff.from(lfun)->in(1)    << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "value of differential from qfun in 2.1  = " << diff.from(qfun)->in(2.1)  << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "value of differential from sfun in 0.12 = " << diff.from(sfun)->in(0.12) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=====-===== 1 =====-=====" << std::endl;
    Fun* comp = new Compound(lfun, qfun);
    std::cout << "value of compound function " << comp->value(2) << std::endl; // Result from: qfun( lfun( 2 ) )

    delete lfun;
    delete qfun;
    delete sfun;

    std::cout << "=====-===== 1 =====-=====" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Compound func still works: " << comp->value(2) << std::endl;

    delete comp;
}
/*********************************** OUTPUT ************************************
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=====-===== 2 =====-=====
-0.8 -1
0.0998334 0
=====-===== 2 =====-=====
-3.99 -4
-3.99 -4
-3.99 -4
=====-===== 2 =====-=====
value of differential from lfun in 1.0  = 2
value of differential from qfun in 2.1  = 4.2
value of differential from sfun in 0.12 = 0.992792
=====-===== 1 =====-=====
value of compound function 5
=====-===== 1 =====-=====
Compound func still works: 5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*******************************************************************************/
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I'll try. I kinda know how to do it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik could you help me with other questions? Is my class hierarchy ok or should I change it? What I can do to make my code better quality?